# How to code template variables transform uppercase|lowercase|captalize in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I need to convert same variables to uppercase|lowercase|captalize.

```
/**
 * @package     ${1 default="Hello"}
 * @subpackage  ${com}_${1 capitalize=false}
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2012 ${AtomTech}, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is very easy to solve it, see:

`${1/(.+)/\L\1/g}`

`${var_name/regex/format_string/options}`

`var_name = 1`

`regex = (.+)`

`format_string = \L\1 (can use l|L|u|U)`

`options = g`

See more in http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/snippets.html

Answer (score 14):

Uppercase

```
${name?upper_case}
```

Lowercase

```
${name?lower_case}
```

Capitalize

```
${name?capitalize}
```

Netbeans uses [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) for its template language.
The documentation specific to your request is [on the page about strings](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for Options > Editor > Code Templates, is that normal?